# Help with Implicit Differentiation: Finding an equation for a tangent to a given point on a curve

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, derivatives, implicit-differentiation

When working through a problem set containing Implicit Differentiation problems, I've found that I keep getting the wrong answer compared to the one listed at the back of my book.

The problem is given as such:
*Use implicit differentiation to find the equation of the tangent line to the curve at a given point*

> x^2 + xy + y^2 = 3

With given point *(1, 1)*. I also am told that it is an ellipse.

To solve this, I evidently must differentiate both sides of the problem:

> **1:** dy/dx ( x^2 + xy + Y^2 ) = dy/dx(3)
>
> **2:** dy/dx (2x + 1y'+ 2yy') = 0
>
> **3:** 1y' + 2yy' = 0 - 2x
>
> **4:** y'(1+2y) = -2x
>
> **5:** y' = -2x/(1+2y)

Hurray, so now since I have the first derivative of Y. I can use it to find the slope at the point.

> **Slope at Point (1,1)=** -2(*1*) / (1+2(*1*)
>
> **Slope at Point (1,1)=** -2/3

So now that I've got my slope, I know the equation of the tangent will be in the form:

> y=mx+b

So, given I now know the slope:

> y=-2/3x + b

Substitute in the known point:

> 1 = -2/3(1) + b

**b = 5/3**

So the final answer I get is: **y = -2/3x + 5/3**

But according to the answer, it is supposed to be: **-x + 2**, I don't know where I went wrong, and I've done it twice to make sure I'm getting the same answer. Could someone please help me?

Comment: The differentiation of $xy$ requires the product rule: $\frac{d}{dx}(xy)=y+xy'$.

Comment: Consider the product rule on the term $xy$: It should read: $\frac{d}{dx}(xy) = \frac{d}{dx}x \cdot y + x \cdot \frac{d}{dx}y.$

Comment: @Clayton: AH! Fantastic find! I never saw that

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You made an error when you differentiated implicitly.  You did not apply the Product Rule $(fg)' = f'g + fg'$ to the term $xy$.  Keeping in mind that $y$ is a function of $x$, you should obtain

$$(xy)' = 1y + xy' = y + xy'$$

Therefore, when you differentiate

$$x^2 + xy + y^2 = 3$$

implicitly with respect to $x$, you should obtain

$$2x + y + xy' + 2yy' = 0$$

Solving for $y'$ yields

\begin{align*}
xy' + 2yy' & = -2x - y\\
(x + 2y)y' & = -2x - y\\
y' & = -\frac{2x + y}{x + 2y}
\end{align*}

As you can check, evaluating $y'$ at the point $(1, 1)$ yields $y' = -1$.  Therefore, the tangent line equation is $y = -x + 2$.